# Can't Run Method and Its GUI From Inside a Try Catch

Tags: java, user-interface, try-catch

I am trying to execute the lines:

```
  Balldemo bd = new BallDemo();
  bd.bounce(myInt);
```

In the below code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    String text = textField.getText();
    try {
      myInt=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
      BallDemo bd = new BallDemo();
      bd.bounce(myInt);
      int newInt = myInt + 5;
      System.out.println("Integer is: "+newInt);          
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      System.out.println("Not a number");

   }

         //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
      textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

But is does not boot the program correctly as follows:
program is a canvas with two balls that move, bounce(int numberOfBalls) will draw the balls on the canvas and start them moving.

In the above code, the canvas is created but the balls do not appear.

However, in a different class under the main method it works fine.

Basically don't understand why it won't successfully execute in a try-catch loop.

Comment: This probably has less to do with the try-catch structure, and more to do with the fact that the entire thing is in an actionPerformed method.  Are you sure your callback is being invoked?

Comment: So I should make it its own method that can be invoked from inside the actionPerformed method?

Comment: Ed, I think you may need to post more of your program. We don't know what's happening inside of BallDemo, but it isn't being passed a canvas object to write to, so what is it drawing on?

Comment: the canvas is held in a field in the BallDemo Object. I tried to link the bounce() method but it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your BallDemo object (bd) is going out of scope as soon as the try block ends. Try declaring it outside the try block.

Comment: thanks but just tried that and didn't make any difference- still have an empty GUI window pop-up.